# IOS PopViewController unexpected animation

Tags: objective-c

While back button pressed in my viewcontroller animation problem occurs.The problem is in the video at the below link:

app.bowerchat.com/images/117_1438022757542.mp4

```
- (IBAction)backChatBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by setting "clipsToBounds" property to YES (true) on base view of your view controller with messages:

Probably in viewWillAppear:

```
\\ View controller with messages (Swift)
override viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.view.clipsToBounds = true
}
```